# Stackoverflow only with very large ArrayLists

Tags: c#, recursion, arraylist, console

I'm using a recursive version of the insertion sort algorithm to sort 5000 objects based upon a randomly generated integer property, but I've been getting a stackoverflow exception only at an ArrayList of this size while working fine for ArrayLists of other sizes.

I used `Console.WriteLine` to see what the "position" integer goes up to in one of my methods and it ends up at `4719 before skipping a line and giving a stackoverflow exception. How should I get around this?

I should also mention that when testing an iterative version of insertion sort in the same Visual Studio solution and using an ArrayList of the same size of objects I do not get a stackoverflow exception.

My code for the recursive insertion sort is below (AL is the ArrayList):

```
public void IS()
{
    ISRM(0);
}

private void ISRM(int position)
{
    if (position == AL.Count)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine(position);
    int PositionNext = position + 1;
    ISRMNext(position, PositionNext);
    ISRM(position + 1);
}

private void ISRMNext(int position, int PositionNext)
{
    if ((PositionNext == 0) || (PositionNext == AL.Count))
        return;

    Webpage EntryNext = (Webpage)AL[PositionNext];
    Webpage EntryBefore = (Webpage)AL[PositionNext - 1];

    if (EntryBefore.getVisitCount() < EntryNext.getVisitCount())
    {
        Webpage temp = EntryBefore;
        AL[PositionNext - 1] = AL[PositionNext];
        AL[PositionNext] = temp;
    }

    ISRMNext(position, PositionNext - 1);
}
```

Comment: What is AL here? And what is the size of it?

Comment: The ArrayList mentioned above, and of 5000 objects.

Comment: Use a `while` or `for` loop instead of recursion.  This site is called StackOverflow for a reason.  The exception is telling you that you can't have a stack depth of 5000.

Comment: @Zer0 why is this site called StackOverflow?

Comment: @RedWei [Voted on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow).  Must say the logo conveys this very issue pretty well.  My complete guess is because it's a well known issue known to many in IT.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, sorting through recursive call is a bad idea for several reasons.

1. As you've already found out, this easily leads to a stack overflow due to limited size of the stack.
2. It will have poor performance by definition since function call and accompanying allocation of local function context on the stack is much more expensive operation compared to something like `while` or `for` operators iterating through plain collection.

These are two reasons why @Zer0 probably suggested it, but there's more to it.

3. There's ready `ArrayList.Sort()` method waiting for you that takes custom comparator. All you need is to write said comparator for your custom objects according to whatever rules you want and call `Sort(your_comparator)`. That's it. You do not need to re-invent the wheel implementing your own sorting method itself - unless implementing sorting method is the actual goal of your program... but I honestly doubt it.

So, It could be something like this (not tested!):

```
class MyComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var _x = ((Webpage) x).getVisitCount();
        var _y = ((Webpage) y).getVisitCount();
        if (_x < _y)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (_x > _y)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myAL = new ArrayList();
// ... filling up the myAL
myAL.Sort(new MyComparer());
```